# How to keep friends from getting notifications about my activity?

Tags: facebook

My Facebook friend gets notifications whenever I post or like something on someone else's profile. This is kind of creepy to me. I liked a mans photo and she immediately came back with ( so in so is nice looking huh) I don't want her to see what I like or comment to other people she is not even friends with them. I know she uses an android phone. How do I keep her from seeing what I do on Facebook besides deleting her.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot control this. Your friends may see what you have liked & commented on their news feed or in their real time ticker.
If necessary, block the people, who you want to be unaware of your activities.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is to never like or comment on posts/pictures that have their visibility set to "Public" or "Friends of friends".

If you only like/comment posts that have their visibility set as friends, then your nosy friend A will not be able to see your activity with your friend B's content ( expect if A and B happen to be friends).